# Swift - activity indicator in static table cells programmatically

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm working with static table cell, i want to hide table view and start activity indicator while i don't receive data from API

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using several approaches and techniques. The simplest one is add an activity indicator to the view controller and set the tableview alpha to 0 while loading the data. After loading the data you can set alpha to 1.0. To animating the activity indicator, you should call

```
  yourActivity.startAnimating()
```

to animating the indicator. And after the data load you can simply call

```
  yourActivity.stopAnimating()
```

to stop animation of the indicator.

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/displaying-an-activity-indicator-while-loading-tab) is a nice tutorial about this process.

Comment: how to set 0 for table alpha?